# wx.media.MediaCtrl - problems with wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STOP, wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED and Load()

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to make a player which will automatically play the next song from a list when the current one ends. Whatever I do, when I add a call to Load() in the on_song_end method of my class binded both to wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STOP or wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, it hangs or just iterates through all the items indefinitely.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import wx
from wx.media import MediaCtrl
from wx.adv import Sound
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
import eyed3
import glob


APP_TITLE = "Crazy ID3 tag editor"


class Window(wx.Frame, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()
        self.create_menu()
        self.update_mp3_listing("D:\\YT")
        self.itemDataMap = self.row_data
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 4)

    def InitUI(self):
        self.row_data = {}
        self.row_obj_dict = {}
        self.now_playing_index = -1
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetLabel(APP_TITLE)
        self.mp3_list_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="List of mp3's")
        self.mp3_list = MyListCtrl(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(-1, -1), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(0, "Artist", width=140)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(1, "Title", width=140)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(2, "Album", width=200)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(3, "Filename", width=200)
        # self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(3, "Year", width=200)
        self.mp3_list.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.on_list_item_activate)
        self.mp3_list.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_FOCUSED, self.on_item_focused)
        self.mp3_list.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_CLICK, self.on_col_click)
        self.edit_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="&Edit")
        self.edit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_edit)
        self.refresh_button = wx.Button(self.panel)
        self.refresh_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.refresh_mp3_listing)
        self.refresh_button.Hide()
        self.stop_button = wx.Button(self.panel)
        self.stop_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.stop_song)
        self.stop_button.Hide()
        self.focus_now_playing_button = wx.Button(self.panel)
        self.focus_now_playing_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.focus_now_playing)
        self.focus_now_playing_button.Hide()
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mp3_list_label, pos=(0, 0), span=(1, 2))
        self.sizer.Add(self.mp3_list, pos=(1, 0), span=(1, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.edit_button, pos=(1, 1), span=(1, 1), flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer.AddGrowableRow(1)
        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(0, proportion=3)
        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(1, proportion=1)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Center()
        self.accelerator_table = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_F5, self.refresh_button.GetId()), (wx.ACCEL_ALT, wx.WXK_CONTROL_S, self.stop_button.GetId()), (wx.ACCEL_NORMAL, wx.WXK_MEDIA_STOP, self.stop_button.GetId()), (wx.ACCEL_CTRL, wx.WXK_CONTROL_P, self.focus_now_playing_button.GetId())])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(self.accelerator_table)
        self.Show(True)

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.file_menu = wx.Menu()
        self.open_folder_menu_item = self.file_menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Op&en folder", "Open a folder with MP3s")
        self.menu_bar.Append(self.file_menu, "&File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_open_folder, self.open_folder_menu_item)
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menu_bar)

    def on_open_folder(self, event):
        title = "Choose a directory: "
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, title, style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.update_mp3_listing(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()

    def on_edit(self, event):
        focused_item = self.mp3_list.GetFocusedItem()
        selected_items_count = self.mp3_list.GetSelectedItemCount()
        if focused_item >= 0:
            if selected_items_count == 1:
                if focused_item == self.now_playing_index:
                    self.stop_song(event=None)
                mp3 = self.row_obj_dict[self.mp3_list.GetItemData(focused_item)]
                dlg = EditDialog(mp3)
                dlg.ShowModal()
                self.update_mp3_listing(self.current_folder_path)
                dlg.Destroy()
                self.mp3_list.Focus(focused_item)
            else:
                mp3s_to_edit = []
                item = self.mp3_list.GetFirstSelected()
                while item != -1:
                    mp3 = self.row_obj_dict[self.mp3_list.GetItemData(item)]
                    mp3s_to_edit.append(mp3)
                    item = self.mp3_list.GetNextSelected(item)
                dlg = EditArtistDialog(mp3s_to_edit)
                dlg.ShowModal()
                self.update_mp3_listing(self.current_folder_path)
                dlg.Destroy()
            self.mp3_list.Focus(focused_item)

    def update_mp3_listing(self, folder_path):
        self.current_folder_path = folder_path
        self.mp3_list.ClearAll()
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(0, "Artist", width=140)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(1, "Title", width=200)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(2, "Album", width=140)
        self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(3, "Filename", width=200)
        # self.mp3_list.InsertColumn(3, "Year", width=200)
        mp3s = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.mp3")
        mp3_objects = []
        index = 0
        for mp3 in mp3s:
            mp3_object = eyed3.load(mp3)
            self.mp3_list.InsertItem(index, mp3_object.tag.artist or " ")
            self.mp3_list.SetItem(index, 1, mp3_object.tag.title or " ")
            self.mp3_list.SetItem(index, 2, mp3_object.tag.album or " ")
            self.mp3_list.SetItem(index, 3, mp3)
            self.mp3_list.SetItemData(index, index)
            # self.mp3_list.SetItemData(index, [mp3_object.tag.artist or " ", mp3_object.tag.title or " ", mp3_object.tag.album or " ", mp3])
            mp3_objects.append(mp3_object)
            self.row_data[index] = (mp3_object.tag.artist or " ", mp3_object.tag.title or " ", mp3_object.tag.album or " ", mp3_object.tag.file_info.name)
            self.row_obj_dict[index] = mp3_object
            index += 1

    def refresh_mp3_listing(self, event):
        self.update_mp3_listing(self.current_folder_path)

    def on_loaded(self, event):
        self.player.Play()
        # self.now_playing_index = self.mp3_list.GetItemData(self.mp3_list.GetFocusedItem()+1)

    def on_list_item_activate(self, event):
        focused_item = self.mp3_list.GetFocusedItem()
        mp3 = self.row_obj_dict[self.mp3_list.GetItemData(focused_item)]
        self.player = MediaCtrl(parent=self, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)
        self.player.Load(mp3.tag.file_info.name) # tried wx.CallAfter without success
        self.player.SetVolume(0.25)
        self.now_playing_index = focused_item
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.on_loaded, self.player)
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STOP, self.on_song_end, self.player)
        if mp3.tag.artist and mp3.tag.title:
            self.SetTitle(f"{APP_TITLE + ': ' + mp3.tag.artist + ' - ' + mp3.tag.title}")
        else:
            self.SetTitle(f"{APP_TITLE + ': ' + os.path.split(os.path.splitext(mp3.tag.file_info.name)[0])[1]} (no tags)")

    def on_song_end(self, event):
        self.player.Stop()
        now = self.now_playing_index
        if now < self.mp3_list.GetItemCount()-1:
            song = self.row_obj_dict[self.mp3_list.GetItemData(now+1)]
            self.now_playing_index = now+1
        else:
            song = self.row_obj_dict[self.mp3_list.GetItemData(0)]
            self.now_playing_index = 0
        print(song.tag.title)
        #self.player.Stop()
        wx.CallAfter(self.player.Load, song.tag.file_info.name)
        """
        if song.tag.artist and song.tag.title:
            self.SetTitle(f"{APP_TITLE + ': ' + song.tag.artist + ' - ' + song.tag.title}")
        else:
            self.SetTitle(f"{APP_TITLE + ': ' + os.path.split(os.path.splitext(song.tag.file_info.name)[0])[1]} (no tags)")
        """

    def stop_song(self, event):
        self.player.Pause()
        self.now_playing_index = -1
        self.SetTitle(APP_TITLE)

    def focus_now_playing(self, event):
        if self.now_playing_index >= 0:
            self.mp3_list.Focus(self.now_playing_index)
            self.mp3_list.Select(self.now_playing_index, on=1)
        else:
            Sound().PlaySound("c:/windows/media/Windows Ding.wav", wx.adv.SOUND_ASYNC)

    # mixin methods override

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.mp3_list

    def on_col_click(self, event):
        old_order = self.mp3_list.GetColumnsOrder()
        self.mp3_list.SortItems(1)
        new_order = old_order
        clicked_column = new_order.pop(self.mp3_list.GetColumnIndexFromOrder(event.GetColumn()))
        new_order.insert(0, clicked_column)
        self.mp3_list.SetColumnsOrder(new_order)
        self.mp3_list.RefreshItems(0, self.mp3_list.GetItemCount()-1)
        # event.Skip()

    def on_item_focused(self, event):
        # print(self.mp3_list.GetItemData(self.mp3_list.GetFocusedItem()))
        pass


class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, autoSizeColumn="LAST", itemTextCallable=None, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        if itemTextCallable is not None:
            if not isinstance(itemTextCallable, Callable):
                raise TypeError("itemTextCallable should be None or a callable")
            self._itemTextCallable = itemTextCallable
        else:
            self._itemTextCallable = self._super_itemTextCallable
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=style)
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.setResizeColumn(autoSizeColumn)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_DESTROY, source=self, id=self.GetId, handler=self._onDestroy)

    def _onDestroy(self, evt):
        evt.Skip()
        self._itemTextCallable = None

    def _super_itemTextCallable(self, item, column):
        return super(MyListCtrl, self).OnGetItemText(item, column)

    def OnGetItemText(self, item, column):
        return self._itemTextCallable(item, column)

    def sendListItemFocusedEvent(self, index):
        evt = wx.ListEvent(wx.wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_FOCUSED, self.Id)
        evt.EventObject = self
        evt.Index = index
        self.ProcessEvent(evt)


app = wx.App()
window = Window(None, title=APP_TITLE)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: in `on_song_end` you call `self.player.Stop()`, which generates another `wx.EVT_MEDIA_STOPPED`/`FINISHED`, so the function loop through itselfs infinitely, i don't think (but I'm not sure) that you need to stop the media if it has already finished, so maybe you can try to remove this string, or instead try to use [wx.EventBlocker](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.EventBlocker.html)

Comment: it works? i have the same problem

Comment: No, still happens the same weird thing.